# I am not seeing where to mark a response as the answer - it's not visible on my page

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I have a question about my Super User post: [Is there a secure way to provide outside access to a computer inside a cablemodem LAN?](https://superuser.com/questions/1491482/is-there-a-secure-way-to-provide-outside-access-to-a-computer-inside-a-cablemode)

One of the comments says

"As the problem seems to be solved, you might accept the answer (tick the V)"

I would like to mark it as solved, but I do not see anything to tick - there seems to be no where to click on my page to mark it as the answer.

Comment: You  [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button). It is below the voting buttons at the top left of the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I accept an answer, and what are the rules?

> To accept an answer, click the "check mark" button underneath the vote
> buttons:
>
> [image]
>
> Additionally:
>
> - Only one answer at a time can be the "accepted" answer.
> - There's a brief period (15 minutes) immediately after asking the question when you can't accept any answer.
> - You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Source [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/267099)

Answer (score -2):

I saw this when I searched for how to do it, but my screen doesn't have it! There's nothing below the up/down vote triangles.

Comment: Maybe because formally you are [this user](https://superuser.com/users/1047636/mlevin77) and the question in question belongs to [this other user](https://superuser.com/users/660772/mike-levin). See [this](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).